# Postgres - SQL Query Delete based on another table

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql

**I cant figure out how i can convert this query to a DELETE-statment.**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT carts.id, shows.date from carts
INNER JOIN tickets on tickets.cart = carts.id
INNER JOIN actseats on actseats.ticket = tickets.id
INNER JOIN showacts on actseats.showact = showacts.id
INNER JOIN shows on shows.id = showacts.show
WHERE Shows.date >= '2017-05-05';
```

**The cart i get from this query is the one i want to delete..In a Delete-statment.**

Comment: three vendors?..

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH val AS (
SELECT DISTINCT carts.id cartid, shows.date from carts

INNER JOIN tickets on tickets.cart = carts.id

INNER JOIN actseats on actseats.ticket = tickets.id

INNER JOIN showacts on actseats.showact = showacts.id

INNER JOIN shows on shows.id = showacts.show

WHERE Shows.date >= '2017-05-05' )
DELETE FROM carts WHERE carts.id IN (SELECT cartid FROM val)
```

Comment: Assume this was downvoted due to using delete from `table` instead of delete from `carts`.  Updated.

Answer (score -1):

you could try

```
delete from carts where id in (SELECT DISTINCT carts.id from carts

INNER JOIN tickets on tickets.cart = carts.id

INNER JOIN actseats on actseats.ticket = tickets.id

INNER JOIN showacts on actseats.showact = showacts.id

INNER JOIN shows on shows.id = showacts.show

WHERE Shows.date >= '2017-05-05');
```

I hope this help you.